# How can I recover Samsung Galaxy contacts?

Tags: contacts, data-recovery

I lost all of my Samsung Galaxy contacts by accident. Is it possible to recover my Samsung Galaxy Contacts? How can I restore contacts from Samsung Galaxy? I've tried many way, but doesn't work.

Comment: We probably need more information than this in order to help you. What are some of these "many way" you've tried to recover your data?

Answer (score 0):

Is your phone synced to your Google account? If yes, go to https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?pli=1#contacts then click on the "More" button and select "Restore Contacts".

Google saves all changes that were made to your contacts in the last 30 days.